# Can't create table errno: -1

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I installed magento CE 1.9.1.0 nothing else! After installation I created a product. When I save the product, magento can't CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE.

The failure notice:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'database.catalogrule_product_price_tmp' (errno: -1),
```

query was:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE `catalogrule_product_price_tmp` 
  ( 
     `grouped_id`        VARCHAR(80) NULL comment 'Grouped ID', 
     `product_id`        INT UNSIGNED NULL comment 'Product ID', 
     `customer_group_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL comment 'Customer Group ID', 
     `from_date`         DATE NULL comment 'From Date', 
     `to_date`           DATE NULL comment 'To Date', 
     `action_amount`     DECIMAL(12, 4) NULL comment 'Action Amount', 
     `action_operator`   VARCHAR(10) NULL comment 'Action Operator', 
     `action_stop`       SMALLINT NULL comment 'Action Stop', 
     `sort_order`        INT UNSIGNED NULL comment 'Sort Order', 
     `price`             DECIMAL(12, 4) NULL comment 'Product Price', 
     `rule_product_id`   INT UNSIGNED NULL comment 'Rule Product ID', 
     `from_time`         INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' comment 'From Time', 
     `to_time`           INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT '0' comment 'To Time', 
     INDEX `idx_mmcatalogrule_product_price_tmp_grouped_id` (`grouped_id`) 
  ) 
comment='CatalogRule Price Temporary Table' 
engine=innodb 
charset=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

My server meets the requirements for Magento. i checked it with the magento-check.php:

```
Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento.
You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)
Safe Mode is off
You have MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
You have the curl extension
You have the dom extension
You have the gd extension
You have the hash extension
You have the iconv extension
You have the mcrypt extension
You have the pcre extension
You have the pdo extension
You have the pdo_mysql extension
You have the simplexml extension
```

Does anyone have an idea or have had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the [InnoDB Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html):

> 1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)
>
> Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.

Not helpful, though :-(

Never heard of this error. You should check the permissions of your tables, make sure you have enough free space left and maybe just drop the table and reinstall magento.